# C# webbrowser upload file

Tags: c#, file, webbrowser-control, uploading

Hello I have problem with select file to upload in a `WebBrowser`, I try do this like that:

```
var elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement file in elements)
{
    if (file.GetAttribute("type") == "file")
    {
        file.Focus();
        file.InvokeMember("click");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        IntPtr fileDownloadDialogPointer = FindWindow(null, "select file dialog");
        SetForegroundWindow(fileDownloadDialogPointer);
        //SendKeys.SendWait("text");

        InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry("text");
        }
    }
```

but this isnt working. How to fix it? I want to insert text in field in Select File Dialog.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Yeah you are right, thanks.

Comment: what do you mean is not working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html

Comment: Do you get the handle of your filedialog? Is it the window having the focus? Does the input in the window have the focus? What is inputsimulator?